# How to update a column in mysql database when value is a date variable

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem when I updated the column `parseDate`.

I am using PHP to update the column value, but always fail.

I tried directly use query in MySQL, it's work.

The value is `$parseDateText`.

I tried

```
$parseDateText = '`'.$parseDateText.'`' ;

$parseDateText = '"'.$parseDateText.'"' ;

$parseDateText = "\"".$parseDateText."\"";

$parseDateText = "\'".$parseDateText."\'";
```

But all of `$parseDateText` showed error message: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064.`

The query is `$sql1`, please help me.

By the way, the column "parseDate" is VARCHAR(30), it should be OK no matter what I update the text.

```
<?php
$parseDateText = date ("Y-m-d");
$parseDateText = mysql_real_escape_string ($parseDateText);
$parseDateText = str_replace('"', "", $parseDateText);
$parseDateText = '`'.$parseDateText.'`' ;

// $test = printf "%s, $parseDateText";

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password
    );

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql1 = "UPDATE TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate = $parseDateText";

    $conn->exec($sql1);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    sleep (1);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL seems strange:

```
UPDATE TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate = $parseDateText
```

The SQL syntax for `UPDATE` in MySQL is `UPDATE <table name> SET ...`

So if your table name is, say `MyTable`, you should use:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET parseDate = '$parseDateText'
```

No need for quotes in the `$parseDateText` variable itself, i.e. it should be like `2015-02-02` rather than `"2015-02-20"` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the support.
`2015_02_20` is the table's name. The original program is parse a target and insert in MySQL. I need to parse it from Mon. to Fri.
So that's why I need to set a variable.

Comment: Thanks~~ it works after I delete the "TABLE". But.....why? I just copy the query from the internet, and it can work in SQL command.

Comment: @Atimis on the internet they reference it as `UPDATE table` assuming you'll replace `table` with the actual name of the table. Maybe they should use `UPDATE <table>` for syntax, but a lot of sites assume you already know this.

Comment: @Atimis Good to hear that it worked. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

remove these lines:

```
$parseDateText = str_replace('"', "", $parseDateText);
$parseDateText = '`'.$parseDateText.'`' ;
```

and try:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate ='". $parseDateText ."'";
```

Comment: And remove the lines `$parseDateText = str_replace('"', "", $parseDateText);` and `$parseDateText = '`'.$parseDateText.'`' ;`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate ='2015-02-20'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I would prepare the statement, instead of appending to it.

Try this:

```
<?php

$parseDateText = date("Y-m-d");

$parseDateText = mysql_real_escape_string($parseDateText);
$parseDateText = str_replace('"', "", $parseDateText);
$parseDateText = '`' . $parseDateText . '`';

// $test = printf "%s, $parseDateText";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql1 = "UPDATE TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate = ?";

    $conn->prepare($sql1, array($parseDateText));

    $conn->exec($sql1);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    sleep(1);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Prepare the statement then execute:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE TABLE 2015_02_20 SET parseDate = ?";

$conn->prepare($sql1, array($parseDateText));

$conn->exec($sql1);
```